# Having issues reading a jpeg file in c

Tags: c

I am currently stuck on  being able to ready a jpeg file. It looks like I'm close, but for whatever reason, the file is not reading the distinct signature(s) of a jpeg file.And of course, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or clumsy or what. Here is the code I currently have:

```
int main (void)
{
    typedef unsigned char BYTE ;
    char image_name[8]; 
    int counter=1;
    FILE* fp = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    FILE *outfile=NULL;
    int size=512;
    BYTE buffer[size];
    while (feof(fp) == false) 
    {
        fread(buffer,size,sizeof(unsigned char),fp);
        if (fp== NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file \n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(buffer[0]==255 && buffer[1]== && || buffer[2]==255 && (buffer [3]==224 && buffer[3]==225))
        {  
            for(int i=0; i<51; ++i){        
                sprintf(image_name, "%.3d.jpg", counter);        
                outfile= fopen(image_name, "w");
                fwrite(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,outfile); 
                counter=counter+1;
                if (outfile == NULL)              
                {                   
                    printf("could not create jpeg file\n");                   
                    return 2;              
                }      
            } 
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(&outfile);
        return 0;
    }
```

Now, currently I'm only part way through this assignment.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but you mention it's an "assignment". If it's homework I would add the "homework" tag, lots of people get bent out of shape 'bout that 'round these parts. Good luck!

Comment: @Chris: no. Please read the homework tag wiki. Do not use that tag.

Comment: I recommend you don't share the entire code of one assignment, just the specific part you have doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of the `if(buffer[0]==255 && buffer[1]== && ||` is not correct.

There should be some value after `buffer[1]==` instead of `&&`.

Is that typo in post?

Comment: It is a type. It was suppose to be buffer[1]==224 I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You open the file in *text mode*, but you should open it in *binary mode*:

```
fopen("card.raw", "rb");  /* Notice the `b` for binary mode */
```

The same when you open for writing.

---

You also only read a *single* character, but then check multiple:

```
/* This reads a single byte (`sizeof(unsigned char)` == 1) */
fread(buffer,size,sizeof(unsigned char),fp);

/* Here you check multiple bytes in the buffer,
 * even though you only have read a single byte
 */
if(buffer[0]==255 && buffer[1]== && || buffer[2]==255 && (buffer [3]==224 && buffer[3]==225))
```

Also note that the expression `buffer [3]==224 && buffer[3]==225` can *never* be true.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on that being the problem — any POSIX-conformant system, including Linux and OS X, treats all files as binary, and ignores the "b" flag. I believe that would only cause problems on Windows.

Comment: @MattPatenaude Well, the OP doesn't specify platform, but errors like this is usually because using the wrong mode on Windows.

Comment: I did that, but still nothing.It seems that maybe the problem is not so much my code but maybe the file? I was told the file is not corrupt and is legit..

Comment: @user2014904 You only read a single byte, but check multiple. Please see my updated answer.